# Не мапится порт docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Запускаю докер. Сервис поднимается на 5000 порту внутри контейнера. Я делаю маппинг 5001:5000. Но сервис доступен на 5000, а не на 5001.  `docker-compose -f .deploy/docker-compose.full.yml up`

```
version: '2'
services:
    storage-local:
        image: "mongo:4.0.2"
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
    storage-api-local:
        environment:
          - ENV_FILE=.deploy/.envs/local.env
        build:
          context: ..
          dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "5001:5000"
        volumes:
          - ..:/app
        depends_on:
          - storage-local
        network_mode: host
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install —upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y git

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make deps
CMD PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make run
```

Comment: Исходя из того что вы написали - "сервис внутри контейнера по-прежнему доступен на 5000 порту, а не на 5001". А в чем вопрос то ? Внутри контейнера сервис будет иметь именно тот порт на котором он работает.

Comment: @zalex Проблема в том, что снаружи порт также 5000, а должен быть 5001, очевидно

Comment: Не очевидно. Вы пишите что сервис по прежнему доступен на порту 5000 . В каком месте он у вас по прежнему доступен ? Как он вообще может быть доступен по прежнему если он запущен в докере ?

Comment: Окей, убрал "по-прежнему". Вопрос остался. @zalex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите что прицепился в комментариях прежде чем ответить.

Тут все просто. В docker существует несколько сетевых поведений ( драйверов? Как вам угодно). 
У вас судя по конфигу сервис запускается в режиме host, а то поведение которое вы ожидаете это bridge (оно в аккурат по-умолчанию). По сему убираете network_mode из конфига или ставите bridge... Да и вообще давно уже указывать версию 3+ :)

Comment: Если я убираю host, тогда монга не видится. Т.е. как-то линку нужно прокинуть в монгу. Я так и не разобрался как

Comment: У меня как-то были проблемы с 3 версией. Чего-то кажется, оттуда выпилили. Вот я и вернулся на 2. Мне так проще сейчас

Comment: @hedgehogues линки deprecated весьма уже давно, нужно использовать network

Comment: как, в таком случае, сделать доступными из bridge mongo?

Comment: @hedgehogues их нужно связать через сеть. Посмотрите например как тут сделано https://github.com/Kolbasyatin/docker-mpd/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml